# Ubuntu 20.04 installation "Install alongside windows option missing"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8, 20.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04 to my laptop which already has windows 8.1 installed. Ubuntu 18.04 was also installed, but I removed it completely in order to install 'clean' Ubuntu 20.04. Now ubuntu installer successfully starts from my bootable usb, although in installation wizard "Install alongside windows" is missing as it says "This computer currently has no detected operating system". It should be noted that previously, when I installed Ubuntu 18.04, installer detects windows 8 and gives option to install alongside (since then windows 8 is not modified). Some helpful inputs are as below:

BIOS mode is **legacy**:

[image]

BIOS configuration part relating boot options are [like this](https://ibb.co/ftKrmgt). You can find **detailed boot info summary** from [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nmmKRNrfN7/). Up to now, I tried turning off fast startup in windows, disabled hibernation in windows and changed boot order in bios menu, but with no success result. What else can be done?

Comment: Start with the obvious "*you've validated the image was burned correctly?*"

Comment: @dankynanky installer is checking files at each start and does not show any problem